# DeepLearning4j throwing "Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll." error

Tags: java, deeplearning4j, dl4j

Recently i started to learn DeepLearning4j library , so i cloned a dl4j project and executed in eclipse.

After executing , it showed following error:

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.
```

I checked my windows path variables and i could not find any variable of name  MKL.

Following are the dependency that i used in the pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a version of dl4j that's more than a year old. Please update to something we support and try again. Our website does not even mention this version. Please use the quickstart docs for the latest version:  https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-quickstart

Thanks!